# How to resolve failure of JAX_WS web service invocation "MustUnderstand headers are not understood"?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client

I'm using SOAPUI tool to access JAX-WS web services deployed in Weblogic 10.3.2

Request:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.pc3.polk.com/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2010-12-03T21:10:43Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2010-12-03T21:44:03Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-60" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2010-12-03T20:10:39Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2010-12-03T20:43:59Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-59" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>rwerqre</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">ewrqwrwerqer</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Nmw0ksmiOX+hkiSoWb2Rjg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2010-12-03T20:10:39.649Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:getMetadata/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
         <faultstring>MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure a dummy SOAPHandler for `{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security` that would mark this header as 'understood'.

Or you could change the SOAP request (on the caller side) to set `mustUnderstand="0"` in the security header.

Example security SOAP header with `mustUnderstand="0"`:

```
<S:Header xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
         <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
         <wsse:Password wsse:Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</S:Header>
```

Comment: I would love to see more details on "configure a dummy SOAPHandler for {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security that would mark this header as 'understood'."

Comment: I'd also like to see such a dummy SOAP Handler

Comment: Just implement a [SOAPHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html) that returns `{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security` from `getHeaders()` but whose `handle..` methods do nothing (return true). That's it.

Comment: In my case even call is not coming `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`,  its going away from `SoapMessageDispatcher` of  `handleHeaders()`. Could you please guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260277/could-not-handle-mustunderstand-headers-http-docs-oasis-open-org-wss-2004-01

Answer (score 7):

After much research, this article solves this issue.

http://dwuysan.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/jax-ws-wsimport-and-the-error-mustunderstand-headers-not-understood/#comment-215

Answer (score 3):

As per WS security specification: 
  The processor MUST, after decrypting the encrypted header block, process the decrypted header block according to the SOAP processing guidelines. The receiver MUST raise a fault if any content required to adequately process the header block remains encrypted or if the decrypted SOAP header is not understood and the value of the S12:mustUnderstand or S11:mustUnderstand attribute on the decrypted header block is true. Note that in order to comply with SOAP processing rules in this case, the processor must roll back any persistent effects of processing the security header, such as storing a received token.
 So please check Configuration of CallbackHandlers.

Comment: Ah, overarchitected specifications standing in the way of getting things done, once again.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with the Handlers. You need to add following in handler implementation

```
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    final QName securityHeader = new QName(
        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
        "Security",
        "wsse");

    final HashSet headers = new HashSet();
    headers.add(securityHeader);
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260277/could-not-handle-mustunderstand-headers-http-docs-oasis-open-org-wss-2004-01 ?

Answer (score -2):

In SOAP UI Navigator,

right-click your project->Show Project View->WS-Security Configurations->Outgoing WS-Security Configurations
**Uncheck** Must Understand, and then send request.